# Reading data from file to execute Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a 'testfiles' files that has list of files
Ex-
Tc1
Tc2

calling above file in script

```
test=`cat testfiles`
for ts in $test
do  
    feed.sh $ts >>results

done
```

This script runs fine when there only 1 test file in 'testfiles',but when there are multiple files ,it fails with 'file not found'

Let me know if this is correct approach

Answer (score 0):

you ll have to read files one by one since you are taking testfiles='Tc1 Tc2' cat is searching for file named 'Tc1 Tc2' which does not exist so use cut command with " " as the delimiter and rad files one by one in a loop.or u can use sed command also to seperate file names

Comment: The testcases are on 2 different lines like- Line 1-TC1 and Line 2-TC2

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work if the filenames have no spaces or other tricky characters.  An approach that handles spaces in file names successfully is:

```
while IFS= read -r ts
do
    feed.sh "$ts" >>results
done <testfiles
```

If your file names have newline characters in them, then the above won't work and you would need to create `testfiles` with the names separated by a null character in place of a newline.

Let's consider the original code.  When `bash` substitutes for `$test` in the `for` statement, all the file names appear on the same line and `bash` will perform word splitting which will make a mess of any file names containing white space.  The same happens on the line  `feed.sh $ts`.  Since `$ts` is not quoted, it will also undergo word splitting.